# Registering custom Form View Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework3

With ZF2, it was very simple to register custom view helpers for custom form elements.

You could simply create an element like such:

```
use Zend\Form\Element;

class Recaptcha extends Element
{
    protected $attributes = [
        'type' => 'recaptcha',
    ];

    protected $secret;

    public function getSecret()
    {
        return $this->secret;
    }

    public function __construct($secret)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->secret = $secret;
    }
}
```

Create a matching helper:

```
use Zend\Form\ElementInterface;
use Zend\Form\View\Helper\FormElement;

class Recaptcha extends FormElement
{
    public function render(ElementInterface $element)
    {
        return '<div class="form-group">
            <div id="register_recaptcha">
                <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="' . $element->getSecret() . '"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="//www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>';
    }
}
```

And then wire it up at config:

```
return [
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            Recaptcha::class => RecaptchaFactory::class,
        ],
    ],

    'view_helpers' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'recaptcha' => RecaptchaHelper::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

IIRC, you would have to wire it up in the Bootstrap too

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $application = $e->getApplication();
    $services = $application->getServiceManager();
    $services->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('FormElement')->addType('recaptcha', 'recaptcha');
}
```

Upgrading a project from ZF2 to ZF3, the custom element now appears as a textfield.

If I call the helper directly on the field, it renders properly:

```
{{ recaptcha( user_form.get('recaptchafield') ) | raw }}
```

**It's the automatic association that's seemingly vanished.**  Such that calling formRow on each doesn't invoke the helper.

Anyone have the quick fix?  Hopeful to save myself from reviewing the actual zend-form and zend-view code.

Thank you!

Comment: Was this ever solved? Have run into the same issue. Gotten as far as creating a new Element with its own `type`. However, renders as Text, because it doesn't know to get the `TypeElement` ViewHelper.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by replacing

```
    $services->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('FormElement')->addType('recaptcha', 'recaptcha');
```

with

```
    $services->get('ViewHelperManager')->get('FormElement')->addClass(Recaptcha::class, RecaptchaHelper::class);
```

The config also needed some adaption. It now reads like this:

```
return [
    'form_elements' => [
        'factories' => [
            Recaptcha::class => RecaptchaFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_helpers' => [
        'invokables' => [
            RecaptchaHelper::class => RecaptchaHelper::class,
        ],
    ],
];
```

Hope that helps someone else find the issue faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

Invokables no longer exist in ZF3. You need to move your recatpcha view helper to the factories key instead and wire it up to Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\InvokableFactory::class

Comment: I had tried that!  Unfortunately it didn't lead to render success; it's actually what drove me to post here.  Guess I'll have to dive into formRow and see what's going on.